# email verification link displays "Unknown named parameter $id" in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I used uuid when defining user id.
I am able to receive the email-verification-link in my email box upon user registration, but when i click the verification link this is what shows up [image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the issue started after **upgrading my php version from 7.3 to 8**
 So this is what i did,
I simply **upgraded my laravel packages** by running the command `composer update` in my project root folder and the error was gone.